# Custom Intent Handler using a Completion Block

Tags: swift, completionhandler, siri

I am using a custom Siri intent to ping a server. The function I use to ping returns in a completion block like so:

```
PingKit.trace(host: server.pingURL, maxTraceTTL: 15) { latency, _ in
    // Do something cool here
}
```

When I try to use this in my custom intent handler though, I never get the feeback I want. Is there a specific way to use a completion block function in an intent handler so I can do something like the following successfully?

```
func handle(intent: RunTestIntent, completion: @escaping (RunTestIntentResponse) -> Void) {
    let server = Server(name: "Google",
                        pingURL: "www.google.com",
                        isPingTestable: true,
                        ndtURL: "10.10.43.146:4443",
                        isNDTTestable: true,
                        geo: Geo.NorthAmerica)
   
    PingKit.trace(host: server.pingURL, maxTraceTTL: 15) { latency, _ in
        completion(RunTestIntentResponse.success(result: "Test Complete"))
    }
}
```

Comment: What do the words "I never get the feeback I want" mean? Does your completion code run? If not, why not? If so, what goes wrong? Is it that you are not calling the intent's completion handler until after _your_ completion handler?

Comment: Yes, my completion call within my `handle()` func never gets called. Siri goes thru the motions of 'Just a sec` to `Still trying` to `There's a problem. Please try again`.

Comment: I can add the same completion line just before the `PingKit.trace()` call and everything works fine.

Comment: Well it is up to you to keep tickling Siri so she knows you're working on the intent. See the docs: "Return your response objects within a few seconds. Because Siri and Maps are actively communicating with the user, always return your response as quickly as possible. If it will take more than a few seconds to return your response, return your response with an “in-progress” code to indicate that you are still working on the request."